# Increment enumeration type in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, increment, enumeration

In vhdl I can define my own enumeration type and create a signal of this type:

```
type tp is (red,green,blue,yellow);
signal sg: tp := red;
```

But now I want a for loop to run over all of these states. Something like

```
for i in sg'min to sg'max loop
   <something>
end loop;
```

In c++ there are iterators for this purpose. But in VHDL all I can find is `sg'pos` that converts the signal to a number that I can increment. But I cannot seem to find a way to convert the number back to a signal.

Comment: Do you want to do this in a testbench or in something that's supposed to become hardware? Because if it's the latter: this screams XY problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need:

```
for i in tp'left to tp'right loop
   <something>
end loop;
```

`left and `right are called *type attributes*. They are useful in your testbench, but not recommended for your design. This is because you the synthesiser may change the order of the enumerations, which might cause you problems.

Comment: A synthesis tool may not change the positional values of an enumeration type. The scalar implicitly defined relational ordering operators  (IEEE Std 1076-2008, 9.2.3 Relational operators) wouldn't work. User defined enumeration types are supported for instance in Xilinx (User Guide 901) which also provides blanket support for operators. There's also little need with the use of LUTs for recognizers.

Comment: I'm thinking of something like this: `if state<STATE3 then op <= '1'; end if;` I would be worried that the synthesiser's FSM synthesis could change the order of the states and hence break my code. Would you think such code is OK?

Comment: (5.2.1) "Scalar types consist of *enumeration types, integer types, physical types, and floating-point types*. Enumeration types and integer types are called *discrete types*. Integer types, floating-point types, and physical types are called *numeric types*. All scalar types are ordered; that is, all relational operators are predefined for their values. Each value of a discrete or physical type has a position number that is an integer value." About here you see why the declaration for *universal_integer* is hidden.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 (RTL Synthesis, withdrawn) had ENUM_ENCODING attribute for manually providing positional values and every place mentioned  had a warning that using it would cause disparity between simulation and synthesis (a major no no). It was supported in ISE and Quartus II, likely not in Vivado or Prime (there's no need it was in support of CPLDs with limited OR terms). Synplify Pro may still support it. No synthesis tools should automatically reassign position values (Synplify could be stopped from doing so). I've seen the non-authoritative bit in 'The VHDL Golden Reference Guide'.

Comment: I've also seen the dated FSM coding guidelines on Doulos web site. Any warning should be associated with use of the ENUM_ENCODING attribute itself  (or tools that can automatically change enumeration position values without intervention). The VHDL language definition says enumerated data types are ordered.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the type of the loop parameter where the discrete range is a range of values of a specified scalar type:

```
entity enum is
end entity;

architecture enum_range of enum is
    type tp is (red,green,blue,yellow);
    signal sg: tp := red;
begin
    process (sg)
    begin
        for i in tp range red to yellow loop
            if sg = i then
                report "sg = " & tp'image(sg);
            end if;
        end loop;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

This produces:

> enum.vhdl:12:17:@0ms:(report note): sg = red

**TL;DR explanation**

IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.10 Loop statement

> iteration_scheme ::=
>            **while** condition
>        | **for** *loop*_parameter_specification
>
> parameter_specification ::=
>        identifier **in** discrete_range

and

> For a loop statement with a **for** iteration scheme, the *loop parameter* specification is the declaration of the loop parameter with the given identifier. The loop parameter is an object whose type is the base type of the discrete range. Within the sequence of statements, the loop parameter is a constant. Hence, a loop parameter is not allowed as the target of an assignment statement. Similarly, the loop parameter shall not be given as an actual corresponding to a formal of mode **out** or **inout** in an association list.
>
> For the execution of a loop with a **for** iteration scheme, the discrete range is first evaluated. If the discrete range is a null range, the iteration scheme is said to be *complete* and the execution of the loop statement is therefore complete; otherwise, the sequence of statements is executed once for each value of the discrete range (subject to the loop not being left as a consequence of the execution of a next statement, an exit statement, or a return statement), after which the iteration scheme is said to be *complete*. Prior to each such iteration, the corresponding value of the discrete range is assigned to the loop parameter. These values are assigned in left-to-right order.

5.3.2 Array types, 5.3.2.1 General

> discrete_range ::= *discrete*_subtype_indication | range

5.3.2.2 Subtype indications

> subtype_indication ::=
>        [ resolution_indication ] type_mark [ constraint ]
>
> constraint ::=
>         range_constraint
>       | array_constraint
>       | record_constraint

5.2 Scalar types 5.2.1 General

> range_constraint ::= **range** range
>
> range ::= range_attribute_name
>        | simple_expression direction simple_expression
>
> direction ::= **to** | **downto**

It helps to understand how defining a range as the discrete range works. Without specifying a subtype indication in the discrete range the type is derived from the simple expressions in the range. The type of a numeric literal (9.3.2 Literals) is *universal_integer* convertible to type integer. The type can also be supplied by attribute as Matthew Taylor shows. Only dipping a toe in simple_expression (9.1) term -> factor -> primary, a primary can be a name (attribute name, 8.6) or a literal.

BNF other than found in Annex C (informative) Syntax summary, is normative.